# ANSI SQL 92: find last occurrence of character

Tags: sql, sybase, ansi-sql

I need a ANSI SQL 92 statement to change all characters following the last '/' character to lower case.

On Sybase I would write:

```
update table 
set col = left(col, len(col)-charindex('/', reverse(col))) ||
          lower(right(col, charindex('/', reverse(col))))
```

I can find all functions in ANSI SQL 92 but the REVERSE function, that I just use to find the last occurrence of the slash.

Comment: Why the code should be in ANSI SQL 92?

Comment: It should be ANSI SQL because I would like to execute the same code on Sybase, Oracle and any SQL 92 compliant DB.