# Spacing reading from a String in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a string (with spaces) from which i want to separate the last word. For example:

```
"Steve Jobs" => Jobs
"Stack OverFlow Question" => Questions
```

Is there any function in PL/SQL or SQL so that i am able to get the results as `Jobs` and `Question` separated out?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241090/ansi-sql-92-find-last-occurrence-of-character And I could get you a solution but it unfortunately would require the use of `REVERSE` which I believe is non-standard.

Comment: @Sparky The plsql tag implies Oracle.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure, because some older versions of Microsoft SQL used to be called PL/SQL...   Thanks for adding the tag...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `INSTR` and `SUBSTR`.  `INSTR` tells you the position of a particular character.  Passing a -1 for the start position tells Oracle to start looking at the end of the string backwards toward the front of the string.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select 'Steve Jobs' str from dual union all
  3    select 'Stack Overflow Question' from dual
  4  )
  5  select substr( str, instr( str, ' ', -1 ) + 1 ) last_word
  6*   from x
SQL> /

LAST_WORD
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Jobs
Question
```

Comment: Great Sir, exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in Microsoft SQL.   Concept should work the same with string function changes to Oracle syntax.

```
declare @fldName varchar(30)
set @fldName = 'Steve Jobs'

select reverse(substring(reverse(@fldName),1,charindex(' ',reverse(@fldName))-1))

set @fldName = 'Stack Overflow Question'

select reverse(substring(reverse(@fldName),1,charindex(' ',reverse(@fldName))-1))
```

Comment: Justin's answers is a much better solution, wasn't sure Oracle supported the -1 start position.  Plus, it is a lot easier to read